# How to detect and measure different paths to a specific method with JProfiler?

Tags: jprofiler

I'm using a *marker* method in unwanted if-else code branches: these branches are not slow, but there is a more efficient implementation in the opposite branch. Now I want to use JProfiler to figure out *all* paths (including their *importance*) to these unwanted branches to fix code to run into the preferred branch instead. Also, I want to do this detection/measurement with least profiling overhead.

I found **Sampling** not to work because the *marker* methods executes too fast to have it showing up in the **Hot Spots**. Also, It might not be executed frequently enough.

I couldn't figure out to do it with **Instrumentation** either. Again, the method does not even show up in **Hot Spots**.

In the ideal case, I would tell JProfiler just to monitor my *marker* method with instrumentation and then restrict the call graph only to calls to this *marker* method.

Is this possible? Are there other efficient ways to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use instrumentation for that purpose. Locate the marker method in the call tree, then invoke the

```
Analyze->Calculate Backtraces To Selected Method
```

action in the context menu or the tool bar.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!